# Can I use 'useSWR' with the contentful-client to create pagination?

Tags: javascript, caching, next.js, contentful, swr

I'm trying to create pagination with nextjs and the useSWR hook.

This is how I've currently done it, and it appears to be working... however I read in the docs that the key passed as the first parameter should be a unique string (usually a URL). I'm just passing the index to fetch the correct data. Will my approach mess up the caching? I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly?

*index.js*

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Page from '../components/page'

export default function IndexPage( ) {
  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div>
      <Page index={pageIndex} />
      <button onClick={() => setPageIndex(pageIndex - 1)}>Previous</button>
      <button onClick={() => setPageIndex(pageIndex + 1)}>Next</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And in my *page.js*

```js
import useSWR from 'swr'
import { fetcher } from '../client/fetcher'

function Page({ index }) {
  const { data } = useSWR(index, fetcher)
  console.table(data)

  return <div>nothing here, just testing</div>

}

export default Page
```

And finally the *fetcher.js*

```js
import client from './contentful-client'

export async function fetcher(pageIndex = 1, limit = 3) {
  const data = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: 'posts',
    skip: pageIndex * limit,
    order: '-fields.publishDate',
    limit,
  })

  if (data) {
    return data
  }
  console.log('Something went wrong fetching data')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to move the Contentful data fetching logic to the server as to not expose credentials and logic to the browser. This could be done using [Next.js API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction).

```js
// pages/api/posts.js

import client from '<path-to>/contentful-client' // Replace with appropriate path to file

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const { pageIndex = 1, limit = 3 } = req.query
    const data = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'posts',
        skip: pageIndex * limit,
        order: '-fields.publishDate',
        limit,
    })

    res.json(data)
}
```

You could then refactor the code in your page to make a request against the newly created API route, passing the route URL as the key to `useSWR`.

```js
import useSWR from 'swr'

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then(res => res.json())

function Page({ index }) {
    const { data } = useSWR(`/api/posts?pageIndex=${index}`, fetcher)
    console.table(data)

    return <div>nothing here, just testing</div>
}

export default Page
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this but I'm getting 500 internal server error when visiting /api/posts.

Comment: Do you know specifically what's causing the error in the API route?

Comment: I'm pretty certain its the client.getEntries().

Comment: Nevermind, I was actually looking for another content_type.. I changed to the one I actually have in contentful and now it's working!

Comment: Would you say useSWR is a good choice for this kind of purpose? (pagination and lazy loading)