# Next.js reach .env from /lib without exposing to the client

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

I my next.js blog app I have been trying to setup a global API call:

```
import { createClient } from "contentful";

const client = createClient({
  space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY,
});

const auth_data = await client.getEntries({ content_type: "author" });

export function getAuthors() {
  var authors = [];

  var auth_len = auth_data.items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < auth_len; i++) {
    authors.push({
      authorSlug: auth_data.items[i].fields.name
        .toString()
        .replace(/ /g, "-")
        .toLowerCase(),
      authorContent: auth_data.items[i].fields.description,
      authorFrontMatter: {
        title: auth_data.items[i].fields.name,
        image: "https:" + auth_data.items[i].fields.image.fields.file.url,
      },
    });
  }
  return authors;
}
```

I keep getting `TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken` because the environment variable will not be reached from the /lib foleder where this getAuthor() function is located. If I prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` I could reach the environment variable from the /lib, but at the same time I would expose the variables to the browser.

**Is there a way to reach the environment variable from the /lib WITHOUT exposing them to the browser?**

Comment: Will this run on the client side or the server side?

Comment: If that code is used on the client-side then you have no choice but to expose the environment variable. Do you actually want to use this on the browser? If so, you could proxy the request through an API route to hide the environment variable. See [Can I use 'useSWR' with the contentful-client to create pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66627836/can-i-use-useswr-with-the-contentful-client-to-create-pagination).